# mysql query on WordNet database was working fine and just stop working

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, wordnet

this query is provided by [wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet) itself, and is used for retrieving word information, such as definition, examples etc from a view named dict. it was working fine for a month but now it just stopped working.
beside, this query works fine in phpMyadmin!

```
if ($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT lemma,pos,sensenum,synsetid,definition ,sampleset FROM dict WHERE lemma = ? ORDER BY pos,sensenum"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$Vocab);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($Lemma, $Pos, $Sensenum, $synsetid, $Def1, $Def2);
    while($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        $output[]=array("Pos"=>$Pos,"Sensenum"=>$Sensenum,"Def1"=>$Def1,"Def2"=>$Def2, "pDef"=>'');
    }
    echo "@@*@@"; 
    print json_encode($output);
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Any errors? Does it print the contents of `echo`? Is it possible that it is just returning zero rows because the `where clause` doesn't match? Print the return of `$stmt->execute()`. Try dumping the `$output` array with `var_dump($output)`.

Comment: DId the `$stmt->execute()` return TRUE? What did `var_dump($output)` print? You could put it immediately after the while loop.

Comment: the result is @@*@@NULL

same query in phpMyAdmin results lots of rows!

Comment: var_dump($output) prints NULL

Comment: this query is backed to client by AJAX i am alerting the result, the query results nothing, no errors no result! so weird!

Comment: `the result is @@*@@NULL` - which means the while looping is fetching zero rows. Examine the return results of bind_param, execute, bind_result statements.

Comment: oh! echo($stmt->execute()); results nothing! but bind_param and bind results are ok, so how should i solve the problem?

Comment: The `$stmt->execute()` is supposed to return TRUE as documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php). Also, do you confirm that the type of lemma is string in database? (something like varchar or char)? And do a `var_dump($Vocab)` to see if it has any strange characters (different encodings).

Comment: Also you could comment out the bind_param and execute the query by removing the where clause from the sql statement. At the end of the sql statement put `limit 10` so that it will return you only 10 rows. This will help you narrow down the problem if there is anything wrong with value of `$Vocab` .. or where clause or bind_param.

Comment: as i noticed this query was working totally fine, suddenly it just stop working, yes lemma is string and this query in phpmyadmin works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Check return values at every method/function call and print `mysqli_connect_errno()`, `mysqli_connect_error()` and `mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt)` at relevant places to check for the errors.

The database name may have changed in configuration. The user/password may have changed (if you think they are correct, then run a dummy query like `select now() as c1` and see if that works.

If the dummy query works, run your original query, but by removing where clause, and by limiting rows with `limit 10` clause.

And, if you figured it out, add that information here for future readers.